# Dynamic Subdirectory for VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm using a VirtualDocumentRoot setting on my dev system, so I can easily work on multiple projects without updating the VirtualHosts all over the time.

That currently looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
    ServerName everything.localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

So I can access the directories below /var/www e.g. by calling foobar.localhost.

The problem is that I now also have projects which are working with a different document root directory, e.g. have another src, pub or public folder in the repository so I want to use these, but that differs per project. So the idea was to extend the VirtualDocumentRoot with another level:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/%2
    ServerName sub.everything.localhost
    ServerAlias *.*.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

So I can call these project e.g. with src.foobar.localhost. Unfortunately that conflicts with the previous rule so I can no longer access the "old" projects which don't have an extra subdirectory.

Is there a way of dealing with both of these VirtualHosts/VirtualDocumentRoots in one apache configuration?

An idea I already had was to have another base domain, like localhost2 for the subdirectories, so the ServerAlias would only match that rule, but that's not the preferred solution.

Comment: How do those `vhosts` conflict? Does one hide the other? Does switching the order help?

Comment: It always uses the VirtualHost with ServerAlias *.localhost. So the extra . in the domain seems also to be matched by the asterisk. Switching the order doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

what about symlink the actual root directory into the original vhost dir?

```
ln -sTv /var/www/fullrepo-project.localhost/pub /var/www/project.localhost
```

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. That's definitely an option, but I'll leave the question open, maybe someone can really fix the conflict in the apache config